# Looping through an array of objects to display information

Tags: javascript

I am on a Team Treehouse challenge.

My challenge is to create an array of objects which contains the students info, make a search database for it so when you search for the student, the student will appear.

The additional challenge is to print out the both students if there is 2 students of same name. I also tried adding another little challenge to list all students if user typed "list".

My code:

```
var message = '';
var student;
var search;
var list;

function print(message) {
  var outputDiv = document.getElementById('output');
  outputDiv.innerHTML = message;
}

function getStudentInfo (student) {
  var report = '<h2>Student: ' + student.name + '</h2>';
  report += '<p>Track: ' + student.track + '</p>';
  report += '<p>Points: ' + student.points + '</p>';
  report += '<p>Achievements: ' + student.achievements + '</p>';
  return report;
}

while (true) { 
  search = prompt("Search Student records: Type a name [Martin] or [quit] to exit");

  if (search === null || search.toLowerCase() === "quit") {
    break;
  }
 for (var i = 0; i < students.length; i += 1) {
    student = students [i];
    if (search.toLowerCase() === student.name.toLowerCase()) {
      message = getStudentInfo(student);
      print(message);
      break;
    } else if (search.toLowerCase() === "list") {

        list = '<h2>Student: ' + student.name + '</h2>';
        list += '<p>Track: ' + student.track + '</p>';
        list += '<p>Points: ' + student.points + '</p>';
        list += '<p>Achievements: ' + student.achievements + '</p>';
        print (list);
  }
    }
      }

var students = [ 
  { 
   name: 'Dave',
    track: 'Front End Development',
    achievements: 158,
    points: 14730
  },
  {
    name: 'Jody',
    track: 'iOS Development with Swift',
    achievements: '175',
    points: '16375'
  },
  {
    name: 'Jordan',
    track: 'PHP Development',
    achievements: '55',
    points: '2025'
  },
  {
    name: 'John',
    track: 'Learn WordPress',
    achievements: '40',
    points: '1950'
  },
  {
    name: 'Jordan',
    track: 'Rails Development',
    achievements: '5',
    points: '350'
  }
];
```

Comment: What does it do now?

Comment: Btw,  you don't need the `break` in the if statement in the for loop, since you're looking for multiple students with the same name

Comment: https://w.trhou.se/s32ioz9mea


I snapshotted my treehouse. You can test it on there

Comment: And you should define the array of students before your `while loop`

Comment: How do you mean define?

Comment: In the code you posted, the `students` array is being *defined*: `var students = []` after you use it.  The reason your code works in your actual project is because you put the `students.js` script **above** the `student_report.js` script.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of notable things:

1. This is poor use of a `while` loop and using `while (true)` tends to be error-prone leading to infinite loops. The point of having a `prompt` in a loop would be to continually expect additional input from the user, but since you `break;` out of every loop I don't believe that is your goal. You actually don't need a `while` construct at all.
2. You don't need so many variables to keep track of the program's state. It's fine to repeat `students[i]` twice rather than making a new variable for it, and you can store the user's input as `toLowerCase()` right away since that's all you'll ever be checking.
3. Unless multiple places in your code need to output to the UI, you don't need a separate function for outputting the message. You can just build up the message and output it at the end of the script. My hunch is that this build-up of the final output is your biggest point of confusion, and the extra function call adds to that.

Overall though, it looks like you were pretty close - the following code is actually shorter than what you had and mainly changes how the `output` message is built.

```js
(function() {

var students = [ 
  { 
   name: 'Dave',
    track: 'Front End Development',
    achievements: 158,
    points: 14730
  },
  {
    name: 'Jody',
    track: 'iOS Development with Swift',
    achievements: '175',
    points: '16375'
  },
  {
    name: 'Jordan',
    track: 'PHP Development',
    achievements: '55',
    points: '2025'
  },
  {
    name: 'John',
    track: 'Learn WordPress',
    achievements: '40',
    points: '1950'
  },
  {
    name: 'Jordan',
    track: 'Rails Development',
    achievements: '5',
    points: '350'
  }
];

var i = 0;
var input = '';
var output = '';

function getStudentInfo (student) {
  var report = '<h2>Student: ' + student.name + '</h2>';
  report += '<p>Track: ' + student.track + '</p>';
  report += '<p>Points: ' + student.points + '</p>';
  report += '<p>Achievements: ' + student.achievements + '</p>';
  return report;
}

input = prompt("Search Student records: Type a name [Martin] or [quit] to exit").toLowerCase();

if (input === 'quit' || input.length === 0) {
  return; // or display some message to 'output'
}

for (i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
  if (input === 'list') {
    output += getStudentInfo(students[i]);
  } else if (input === students[i].name.toLowerCase()) {
    output += getStudentInfo(students[i]);
  }
}

document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = output;

})();
```

```css
@import url('http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/3.0.2/normalize.css');

/*General*/
body {
  background: #fff;
  max-width: 980px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 20px;
  font: Helvetica Neue, Helvectica, Arial, serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  color: #8d9aa5;
}

a {
  color: #3f8aBf;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: #3079ab;
}

a:visited {
  color: #5a6772;
}

h1, h2, h3 {
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #384047;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 1.8em;
  margin: 60px 0 40px;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 30px 0 10px 0;
}

#home h2 {
  margin: -40px 0 0;
}

h3 {
  font-size: .9em;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

h3 em {
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin: 0 0 10px 5px;
  padding: 0;
  color: #8d9aa5;
}

ol {
  margin: 0 0 20px 32px;
  padding: 0;
}

#home ol {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 0 40px 0;
}

li {
  padding: 8px 0;
  display: list-item;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  counter-increment: step-counter;
}

#home li::before {
    content: counter(step-counter);
    font-size: .65em;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 300;
    padding: 2px 6px;
    margin:  0 18px 0 0;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background:#8d9aa5;
    line-height: 1em;
}

.lens {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 8px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 8px solid transparent;
  border-right: 8px solid #8d9aa5;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 5px 0 0 -19px;
}

#color div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 5px;
}

span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1>Students</h1>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: In the Team treehouse guide/video, the tutor says that using while(true) is bad practice but says that it is good enough for the task. 


Can you explain what (function() { .... })();  is there for? Why is the like entire code wrapped into the function?

Also have you got any good resources/recommendations for learning JS, or should i stick with Team Treehouse? 

Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: I would strongly disagree - if it's known to be bad practice it shouldn't be used, and as you can see in my code, it's not needed. The `(function()` is called an Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE) which serves two purposes: it immediately runs the function and creates a scope around your code so it doesn't interfere with any other JS libraries you might use (functions create new scopes in JS). For learning, I would recommend a read through http://eloquentjavascript.net/ which focuses on learning JS as well as programming fundamentals.

Comment: Thanks! I will definitely check it out!